How to include exact HLS segment duration in MPEG-TS filename or headers using FFmpeg?
I'm using FFmpeg to create HLS streams from RTSP cameras. I need to know the exact duration of each segment without using ffprobe (too slow) or parsing m3u8 playlists (too resource-intensive).
Here's my current FFmpeg command:
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://camera:554/stream" \
  -c copy -an -f hls \
  -hls_allow_cache 0 \
  -hls_flags omit_endlist \
  -hls_start_number_source epoch \
  -hls_time 10 \
  -hls_list_size 3 \
  -strftime 1 \
  -hls_segment_type mpegts \
  -hls_base_url /stream/camera/full/ \
  -method PUT \
  http://localhost:5000/api/livestream/camera/full/index.m3u8

What I need is either:
Include exact segment duration in the filename (e.g., 20240319143022_10.234.ts)
Or include duration in segment headers/metadata that can be quickly read
I've tried:

Using ffprobe (too slow)
Parsing m3u8 playlists (resource intensive)
Using fixed duration from -hls_time (not accurate enough)

Is there a way to make FFmpeg write the exact segment duration either in the filename or in easily accessible metadata?
